# How to calculate an average error between numerical and analytical solution of the PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

I have second-order initial boundary value problem. Here's my code returning numerical solution (and plotting it).

```
solution = 
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] - x * y * Sin[t], 
   u[t, 0, y] == 0, u[t, 1, y] == Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 1, y], 
   u[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, x, 1] == Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 1], 
   u[0, x, y] == x*y}, u, {t, 0, 6}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
Plot3D[First[u[6, x, y] /. solution], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

In addition, I have analytical solution (just plotting it) [here is Cos[t], t = 6] :

```
Plot3D[x * y * Cos[6], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotPoints -> 40]
```

The question is how to find an average error (difference) between analytical and numerical solutions with specified time T?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your exact definition of "average error", but for example:

```
NIntegrate[Abs@(First[u[6, x, y] /. solution] - (x*y*Cos[6])), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
           AccuracyGoal -> 5]
(* 0.0250133 *)
```

Comment: I guess, that's the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @instajke This is the $L^1$ norm; in general, there is the [$L^p$ norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lp-Space.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Also you may want absolute or relative errors, etc. People tend to think of errors in convoluted ways ...